# Difference between "public relations" and "human relations"

Tags: differences

The other day I was looking at the various job positions in the newspaper just for my knowledge and found that a few companies had *public relations* officer post and some had *human relations* officer post.

What is the difference between the two? Why give a different name when they seem the same?

Comment: Hello 168335! I am afraid this question is off-topic. You can check our FAQ for more info if you want.

Comment: BTW, whats HR and PR? :P

Comment: HR and PR are the short forms for Human relations and Public relations respectively. And, i did not know if this question owuld be off topic in a site such as this,  if other people feel so too, i would request the moderators to take necessary action but would be happy to receive some answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HR (HRD) - Human Resources Department. It is responsible for the staff (employee) management in an organisation. Example responsibilities: Recruiting, Lay-offs, Pay-Packets etc.

PR (PRM) - Public Relations Management. It comprises of all activities done to keep the public involved in the company. PR used to be the 'point of contact' between the (general) public (esp. Media) and the organisation. However, modern PR has donned a more of marketing role. For example, most celebrities hire PR fellows who in turn (through their contacts) get them published in various media, arrange for entry in privileged parties, sustaining a large public interest in them through various means (including fabricating controversies :P ) etc.

Answer (score 1):

**HR** stands for *human resources*, not human relations.

*HR* deals with staffing issues. *PR* (public relations) deals with image issues.

Comment: oh. thanks , my bad for misunderstanding the short forms. thx again

Answer (score 0):

Public relations concern dealing with "people" in the ABSTRACT. That is, putting out news (in the most positive possible light) about a company to create a positive impression of the company among a group of people outside the company (who are not necessarily identifiable).

Human relations (or human resources) concern dealing with people IN THE FLESH. That is, with hiring, training, compensation and promotion of particular INDIVIDUALS, specifically those within the company.